# iptables add ip,port and also IP

Tags: iptables, firewall, ipset

Now I perform this:

```
create blockipset hash:ip
add blockipset 192.168.1.5 -exist
add blockipset 192.168.3.115 -exist
```

Is it possible for iptables and ipset to block ip,port and ip?
for example, the list contains:

```
192.168.1.5
192.168.3.115
192.168.1.55,80
192.168.1.53,22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put different types of elements in the same set with the `ipset` command. But you can use different sets, one for each type (full list available with `ipset help`):

```
hash:ip
hash:ip,port
```

For example:

```
ipset create blocklistip hash:ip
ipset create blocklistipport hash:ip,port

ipset add blocklistip 192.0.2.3
ipset add blocklistipport 192.0.2.2,80
ipset add blocklistipport 192.0.2.3,udp:53
```

Note like above that by default the protocol for the port is TCP unless explicitly stated otherwise (`udp:` for UDP, `sctp:` for SCTP, ...).

Now your script has to check what type of element it got, to know in what *ipset* it will add it. A simple example here would be to check for the `,` to know where to put it, while reading the list from the file `blocklist.txt`:

```
while read -r element; do
    if echo $element|grep -q ,; then
        ipset add blocklistipport $element
    else
        ipset add blocklistip $element
    fi
done < blocklist.txt
```

And you can block everything in the list for example with:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set blocklistip src -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set blocklistipport src,dst -j DROP
```

Above `src,dst` means use the source IP address along the destination port address in the packet when looking for a match in the `hash:ip,port` set.

Also, *ipset* has a special set `list:set` consisting of a list of other sets. This won't change the way to populate separately the sets using the `ipset` command, but you can do this:

```
ipset create blocklist list:set
ipset add blocklist blocklistip
ipset add blocklist blocklistipport
```

and replace the two previous *iptables* rules with only the one below:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set blocklist src,dst -j DROP
```

which goes toward your goal: this single *iptables* rule will work correctly with set elements with or without a port, as [documented in ipset](https://manpages.debian.org/ipset/ipset.8#list:set).